# How to turn off Chrome's auto highlight?

Tags: google-chrome

When I click on a link in chrome, it often auto-highlights some text in yellow, which I hate. How to turn that off? Please provide a step by step guide as I do not know much about modifying browsers and only know python.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/13072916?hl=en

Comment: If that does not work add this extension to chrome>>>https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-google-search-tex/ompocnnmgiaoieoanemepjflbokldhom?hl=en